# Are 60 year old baby clothes safe

Tags: safety

I just has a friend who is sorting out his attic if I would like his sixty year old baby clothes that have been in a suitcase in the attic. His house is damp and has woodworm and subsidence. Should I accept.

Comment: If you need them, sure. Just be sure to wash in very hot water with bleach and add an extra rinse. They may not suit today's styles or lifestyle, though (e.g. no onesies.).

Comment: I am closing this as duplicate because although the time gap is significantly larger, the basic rules for washing and inspecting for damage are the same. In short, we can’t possibly know in what state this specific set of clothes is, but we can help you making an informed decision.

Comment: A caveat I hadn’t considered is flame retardant sleepware.